# Почему у меня не устанавливается соединение websocket?

Tags: php, composer

У меня чат на вебсокетах, использую retchet, поставил composer, запустил сервак вебсокетов через putty. Пытаюсь подключиться: var conn = new WebSocket('wss://site.ru');

ошибка: chatroom.php:138 WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.ru/chat' failed:

Не подключается. Сам путь не правильный может быть? Можете подсказать, новичок пока что в этом деле.

Comment: Эта информация вообще ничего не даёт. Как сервер написали? Как запустили? Открыли ли доступ к портам? Как подключаетесь ("[домен].ru" доступ не даст, требуется проксирование)? Почему ошибка php в принципе, когда подключение идёт через клиент (js)?

Comment: chatroom.php:138 - покажите фрагмент кода, включая используемые в строке данные.. php для вебсокетов.. это жестяк... вы используете wss - у вас используется ssl?

Comment: @Jour Да почему жестяк? Нормально сокеты на PHP через библиотеки работают. Просто изначально не было этого всего, отсюда скепсис, что сторонние разрабы хорошо не сделают... В том же Swoole всё очень даже хорошо, удобно и шустро.

Comment: запускал сервер через putty, подключался, прописывал команду запуска сервера и путь до него
к портам доступ не открывал, а как?